# When does Tech 5 become available for the Rebels in Empire at War?

Tags: star-wars-empire-at-war

I'm playing through Star Wars: Empire at War as the Rebellion. I'm currently at Tech 4, and about to try the ninth mission Raid Over Corulag, but there is no option to steal up to Tech 5.

When is Tech 5 available? I'd like to build Mon Calamari cruisers soon.

Comment: After the Empire discovers it. IIRC the rebels can only get new tech by stealing it from the empire.

Answer (score 2):

You have to steal every technology possible per set of available tech for c3p0 and r2d2. Once you've gotten the available tech in that tech level, a new group will appear for you to steal.

Comment: In addition, you don't unlock your final set of Heros (and presumably, tech level 5) until you've got every tech in the final group. Or at least that's the case in Galactic Conquest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be stealing tech from the empire consistently. After finishing Han's mission at Corulag, you should be automatically bumped up to tech 5. HTH